# Android, Using FileInputStream for reading file from SDC, reporting null pointer error

Tags: android, fileinputstream

I used FileInputStream class when I was trying to read something from my files reside in SDCard, the codes are as follows:
Code:

> filepath = "/sdcard/myfile/testFile"
>   FileInputStream fileIn = null;
>   fileIn = new
>   FileInputStream(filepath);   byte []
>   InBuf = new byte[1024];
>   fileIn.read(InBuf);   Strubg
>   fileContent = new String(InBuf);
>   fileIn.close();

when I ran my program,  android keep reporting null pointer error on my last line:"fileIn.close",  I really didn't know the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked till late last night,  finally, I make it work, though I am not sure if it is exact reason.   I simply tried the following methods, then no more null pointer report came,

```
try  
{
    InputStream fileIn = null;
    filepath = "/sdcard/myfile/testFile";
    fileIn = new BufferedInputStrream(new
    FileInputStream(filepath））;
    byte [] InBuf = new byte[1024];
    fileIn.read(InBuf);
    ...
    ...
    ...  
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
} finally {     
    if(fileIn != null) 
    {       
        try         
        {           
            fileIn.close();         
        } catch(IOException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }   
    } 
}
```

Any way, thank you so much for your help. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myfile/textfile.extenstion"
```

You must be missing the extension.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't miss any permission. NULL pointer exception couldn't be caused by permission missing.